# Passing arguments with whitespace to a command from within a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

**See edit below, thanks**

I have the following test script (**important note: I cannot change this part**):

```
while (($#)); do
  echo $1
  shift
done
```

Running the command
`./test aaa "bbbb cccc" ddd`
gives the following output:

```
aaa
bbbb cccc
ddd
```

which is what any sane person would expect.

I have another script:

```
mode="good"
status="okay"
name="bro"
description="very good man dood"
extra=""

# ----

PARAMS=""

// $1: key, $2: value
function addParam {
    if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
        PARAMS="$PARAMS --$1 \"$2\""
    fi
}

addParam "mode" "$mode"
addParam "status" "$status"
addParam "name" "$name"
addParam "description" "$description"
addParam "extra" "$extra"

echo ./test $PARAMS
./test $PARAMS
```

The output from `echo` is `./test --mode "good" --status "okay" --name "bro" --description "very good man dood"`, so I would expect the output of `./test $PARAMS` to be

```
--mode
good
--status
okay
--name
bro
--description
very good man dood
```

but instead, for some reason, I get the following output:

```
--mode
"good"
--status
"okay"
--name
"bro"
--description
"very
good
man
dood"
```

If I copy the output of `echo ./test $PARAMS` and paste it, I get the expected output from `./test`. So I tried removing the last line which executes `./test` and leave the `echo` line last, but apparently `$(./script)` still does not work and I'm beyond ideas.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** @steeldriver's solution works but there's another constaint - I have to allow users to send their own arguments.

So having this script (thanks @steeldriver):

```
#!/bin/bash

mode="good"
status="okay"
name="bro"
description="very good man dood"
extra=""
arguments="--config \"blablabla=yes\" --config2 \"bla2=no problem\""

# ----

declare -a PARAMS

# $1: key, $2: value
function addParam {
    if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
        PARAMS+=("--$1" "$2")
    fi
}

addParam "mode" "$mode"
addParam "status" "$status"
addParam "name" "$name"
addParam "description" "$description"
addParam "extra" "$extra"

# (1)
PARAMS+=("$arguments")

# (2)
PARAMS+=($arguments)

echo ./test "${PARAMS[@]}" 
./test "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

The desired output is:

```
--mode
good
--status
okay
--name
bro
--description
very good man dood
--config
blablabla=yes
--config2
bla2=no problem
```

However the output I get is:

With `(1)`:

```
--mode
good
--status
okay
--name
bro
--description
very good man dood
--config "blablabla=yes" --config2 "bla2=no problem"
```

With `(2)`:

```
--mode
good
--status
okay
--name
bro
--description
very good man dood
--config
"blablabla=yes"
--config2
"bla2=no
problem"
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: @ZacharyBrady Yes, and the result is that the whole string becomes a single argument (i.e., `--mode "good" --status "okay" --name "bro" --description "very good man dood"` as a single line in the test script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the heads up from @steeldriver, I managed to add the user arguments properly and get the desired output. This is my script now:

```
#!/bin/bash

mode="good"
status="okay"
name="bro"
description="very good man dood"
extra=""
arguments="--config \"blablabla=yes\" --config2 \"bla2=no problem\""

# ----

declare -a PARAMS

# $1: key, $2: value
function addParam {
    if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
        PARAMS+=("--$1" "$2")
    fi
}

# This function right here
function addUserArguments {
    while (($#)); do
      PARAMS+=("$1")
      shift
    done
}

addParam "mode" "$mode"
addParam "status" "$status"
addParam "name" "$name"
addParam "description" "$description"
addParam "extra" "$extra"

# And this line right here
eval addUserArguments $arguments

./test "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

And the output is

```
--mode
good
--status
okay
--name
bro
--description
very good man dood
--config
blablabla=yes
--config2
bla2=no problem
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array rather than a string variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

mode="good"
status="okay"
name="bro"
description="very good man dood"
extra=""

# ----

declare -a PARAMS

# $1: key, $2: value
function addParam {
    if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
        PARAMS+=("--$1" "$2")
    fi
}

addParam "mode" "$mode"
addParam "status" "$status"
addParam "name" "$name"
addParam "description" "$description"
addParam "extra" "$extra"

echo ./test "${PARAMS[@]}"
./test "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

Testing

```
$ ./other.sh
./test --mode good --status okay --name bro --description very good man dood
--mode
good
--status
okay
--name
bro
--description
very good man dood
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I actually have another use case which I did not mention because I didn't think it would be necessary. I've edited the question with that use case and what I've tried.

Comment: @Adidishen for that, I think your script will need to parse the `arguments` string into a sequence of tokens that you can pass individually